# Can I make a vague schema that only requires a root node to be set, regardless of the other elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

This is to be used in BizTalk but I am unsure wether that is relevant for the question.

the xmls that I will be processing look like this.

```
<dcsmergedata>
  <dataheaders>
    <dataheader>
      <element1></element1>
      <element3></element3>
      <element9></element9>
      <datalines>
        <dataline>
          <lineelement1></lineelement1>
          <element3></element3>
          <lineelement6></lineelement6>
        </dataline>
      </datalines>
    </dataheader>
  </dataheaders>
  <datalines />
</dcsmergedata>
```

However, since the interface I will be using will mainly be used for moving the file from two locations and add xml declarations and changing the encoding, only the dcsmergedata element is needed to be there.

I've been trying to work with the  element but I seem to get errors on the sub elements (I'm assuming an any element can't have children?) and if I keep the elements with sub elements defined, I can't use  and  on the same level since the schema can't know which to use (that makes sense though)

Ultimatly, I want a schema that is valid on all xml files with a root note dcsmergedata and can have any elements and sub elements. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to validate your instance against an XSD that simply specifies

```
<xs:element name="dcsmergedata" type="xs:anyType"/>
```